# Git - checkout branch discard local changes

Tags: git

I am working on a `feature` branch where I added and modified a few files.

At one moment I would like to switch to `develop` branch, but I do not want to see the changes I made in `feature` branch.

So I do `git checkout develop` but changes are still there. I am switched to `develop` branch, but changes are still present.

What I would like to accomplish is:

- when I type `git checkout develop` I get to `develop` branch and changes are discarded.
- when I switch back to `feature` branch changes I made in `feature` should be visible again.

The only way I figured out was to:

- stash changes from `feature`
- switch to `develop`
- switch back to `feature`
- apply stash

But I don't like the way of having stashes. Is there any way how to accomplish this with `git checkout` only or without stashes?

Comment: What I do is commit to a new branch with a name like `feature-temp` or `feature-paused` or whatever.  Don't push that branch anywhere, just let it sit on your system.  When you're ready to work on it, switch to that branch and merge it into your feature branch.  I can submit this as an answer, though I don't feel my answer is good enough, as its based on opinion.

Comment: You need to commit or stash your changes while you're on the feature branch first

Comment: I think "alias"es can help here.

Comment: @Amy I like that answer, but Tim's answer below seems a bit better to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like using stash, and I don't personally have any reason to not like using it, then you may try making a temporary commit on the `feature` branch:

```
# work work work
git add <file1>
# ... and add other files
git commit -m 'temporary commit for some feature'
```

Then, you can switch to the `develop` branch to do whatever you have in mind.  When you return to the `feature` branch, you can either just keep working on top of that commit, or try to get back to the original working state.  To get back to what things looked like when you were in the middle of working, you may try doing a mixed reset:

```
git reset --mixed <SHA-1 of temporary commit>
```

This will move the HEAD of your branch back one commit along with the index.  So, you will be left with a working directory containing your in progress work, but without any actual commit on your `feature` branch.  You could now finish the current feature and make a permanent commit.

But note that `git stash` itself is actually implemented under the hood by making two (or sometimes three) commits to store your in progress work.  So, my answer actually uses a similar approach to stash, but with a few differences.

Comment: good idea, I can also amend 'temporary' commit when I am done on feature branch.

Comment: Yes, you can amend as well.  Or do a reset to get your original working directory state back as it was.